Gravity Forms Как подписаться на событие валидации?
В WP используется плагин Gravity Forms с вот таким подключением формы по AJAX отправке
[gravityform id="2" title="false" description="false" ajax="true" required_legend="false"]

Вопрос, можно ли при помощи JS подписаться на событие о том, что форма не прошла валидацию, чтобы выполнить свою функцию?
В документации нашел, про gform_post_render, но оно срабатывает, как только отрисовало форму, а мне надо именно когда при отправке вернуло с ошибкой.
Что-то типа такого:
$(document).on('gform_post_validation', function(formId, isValid) {
    if (formId === 2) {
        console.log("Form ID 2 validation result: " + isValid);

        $('.gfield_contains_required input').each(function() {
            let $label = $(this).closest('.gfield_contains_required').find('label');
            if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
                $label.addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $label.removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }
});

Только там нет метода gform_post_validation

Посоветовали, вот такое решение, в соответствии с рекомендациями.
$(document).bind('gform_post_render', function (e, formId) {
    if ( $('.gform_validation_errors').length > 0 ) {
        if (formId === 2) {
            $('.gfield_contains_required input').each(function () {
                let $label = $(this).closest('.gfield_contains_required').find('label');
                if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
                    $label.removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $label.addClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

проблема была ещё и в том что на странице было сразу несколько форм.
